# Automating browser actions on a headless server

Tags: ruby

I'm looking for a ruby solution to automate web accions on a headless server (no xwindows).

What I need is to daily export a file from a webapp and import it to other web app in other server.

I've seen Selenium, Capybara, Nokogiri, but I'm confused with their differences/similarities. Selenium seems to require a browser running, which I can't have as there is no X to run it. Nokogiri can use Webkit on a headless server, but can't figure out if it can actually download/upload files.

Any pointer would be appreciated.

Comment: What about regular cron task calling calling a Ruby method in your app via `rails runner "Model.method"`?

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the apps I need to connect to are rails nor are in my control. I just have to depend on the web UI.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest [mechanize](https://github.com/sparklemotion/mechanize). I'm not sure that you need something like `selenium` for a task like this.

This gem should be able to accomplish what your looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It's not Ruby, but...I'd strongly consider using something like [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) (+ [CasperJS](http://casperjs.org/), perhaps) or [Zombie.js](http://zombie.labnotes.org/).  They're all JavaScript, but...I'd still see if you can make them work.